# Row color change according to property condition angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am new in angular 4, I am trying to make a p-dataTable and want to change row color according to my object quantity property. If quantity is less then 10 then the row color will be red.

Below is my code :

```
<p-dataTable [value]="myObjectList"
                     selectionMode="single" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true"
                     [pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" [loading]="loading" exportFilename="InventoryDetailsReport" #dt></p-dataTable>
```

I google a lot for two days and find "rowStyleClass" is used in every cases but all example was in ngPrime version 1.0.1

I am working on version 4.1.3 where I am unable to do row color.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rowStyleClass - Function that gets the row data and row index as parameters and returns a style class for the row. This is an alternative to the rowStyleMap approach.

```
<p-dataTable ... [rowStyleClass]="setClass"></p-dataTable>

setClass(rowData) {
  return rowData.quantity < 10 ? 'classOne' : 'classTwo';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jsFan bro for your reply, but I use this process and I am facing a problem => I have three rowData but  "setClass" function call 6 times. And also color not changing. :(

Comment: It is called 6 times because change detection run twice.

Comment: You can verify that the class is added to the element?

Comment: bro I check the inspect element and I can see my declared class is added to the element but css of that class is not applied, don't know why :(